# MySQL any keyword usage

Tags: mysql, sql, any

I am having the following issue:

When I execute the following statement, I get an error for it returning more than one row

```
INSERT INTO artist 
            (personid, 
             musicgenreid, 
             totallikes) 
VALUES     ( (SELECT personid 
              FROM   person 
              WHERE  firstname = 'Joe' 
                     AND middlename = '' 
                     AND lastname = 'blow'), 
             (SELECT musicgenreid 
              FROM   musicgenre 
              WHERE  musicgenreid = 4), 
             ( totallikes = 328374 ) );
```

I am getting the error on the (select pesonID from person...) statement, and I am trying to use the 'any' keyword to just grab any row, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have tried just about any permutation I can think of of the current query and 'any', but it does not work. Is there another solution I should be trying or am I just missing the mark for some reason?

Comment: In order to provide a solution we should first understand the problem. What are you trying to do with that query?

Comment: I am simply trying to insert those values into artist table; the only issue is that the select personid... section can return more than one row, which I am trying to eliminate by using any (so any row that has those values is fine).

Comment: You can use "LIMIT 1" to just get the top one if you are sure they are just duplicates... or you don't care.

Comment: thanks, limit 1 worked!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO artist (personid, musicgenreid, totallikes) 
VALUES (
  (SELECT personid FROM person 
   WHERE  firstname = 'Joe' AND middlename = '' AND lastname = 'blow'
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1
   ),
  4,
  328374
);
```

This will get you a random `personid` that matches the given criteria.

The `musicgenreid` in your query would be either `null` or `4`. I am forcing it to `4` as it seems that you're manually adding them and you know they already exist.

The total likes field is also fixed but your syntax was incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

try with this sql statement

```
     INSERT INTO artist 
            (personid, 
             musicgenreid, 
             totallikes) 
VALUES     ( (SELECT personid 
              FROM   person 
              WHERE  firstname = 'Joe' 
                     AND middlename = '' 
                     AND lastname = 'blow' LIMIT 1 ), 
             4, 
             328374);
```